# Unable to install linux tools in Eclipse

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, upgrade

I am trying to install linux tools in my Eclipse (I want to use valgrind and some
other tools that are inside the package).
The problem is that while trying to install them I get the following error:

```
Software being installed: Remote OProfile Integration 1.0.0.201402102340(org.eclipse.linuxtools.oprofile.remote.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.201402102340)
Missing requirement: Resource Selector Proxy for RDT (Incubation) 0.9.2.201402102340 (org.eclipse.linuxtools.profiling.launch.ui.rdt.proxy 0.9.2.201402102340) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.ptp.remote.core 7.0.0' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Remote OProfile Integration 1.0.0.201402102340 (org.eclipse.linuxtools.oprofile.remote.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.201402102340)
To: org.eclipse.linuxtools.profiling.remote.feature.group 0.8.0
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Profile Framework Remote Capabilities 1.0.0.201402102340 (org.eclipse.linuxtools.profiling.remote.feature.group 1.0.0.201402102340)
To: org.eclipse.linuxtools.profiling.launch.ui.rdt.proxy [0.9.2.201402102340]
```

I search online to find the answer and I found some similar cases but none of them
gave a solution to my problem.
So any suggestion here would be more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it needs Eclipse [PTP](https://www.eclipse.org/ptp/) to be installed.

This should be found automatically if you select `Contact all update sites during install to find required software` on the `Install New Software` dialog (assuming you have main Eclipse update site available).